# update original BindingList binded to filterable DataGridView after cell changed

Tags: c#, datagridview, datasource, bindinglist, filtered

In a winform c# project ,there is a `BindingList` binded to `DataGridView` named `dg` , how can I make that `DataGridView` filterable so when I change a cell in filtered `DataGridView` the original `BindingList` update automatically ? 
I bind `DataGridView` to list like this :

```
BindingList<Input> bl;
BindingSource bs;
bl = new BindingList<Input>(listInput);
bs = new BindingSource(bl, null);
dg.DataSource = null;
dg.DataSource = bs;
```

Comment: There are a lot of missing details. However, if the grid is “filtered” and you want … _”so when I change a cell in filtered DataGridView the original BindingList update automatically”_ … Have you considered wiring up the grids `CellValueChanged` event and simply “remove” the filter? It appears you are using a “Class(Input)” in a `List<Input>`… It is unclear “how” you are “filtering” the list, and I am guessing a `DataTable` may be easier when filtering and sorting.

Comment: thank you @JohnG. I removed the BindingList and I bound bindingsource to listInput directly . now I use bindingsource.filter.